# Get each the "User" of child roles

Tags: mysql, laravel, recursion

Project having six roles which are as follows.

1. Super Admin - He can create Sub super admin, Admin, Super Master, Master and User.
2. Sub Super Admin - He can create Admin, Super Master, Master, User.
3. Admin - He can create Super Master, Master, User.
4. Super Master - He can create Master, User.
5. Master - He can create only User.
6. User - He just use the policies.

So I want to get each the "User" of child roles.

**Users Table**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'object_id',
        'userid',
        'name',
        'balance',
        'role_id',
        'password',
        'is_lock_user',
        'phone',
        'is_direct',
        'access_token',
        'last_login_at'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function clientsOfMine()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'clients', 'user_id', 'client_id');
    }
}
```

**Client Table**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Client extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'client_id'
    ];
}
```

Currently I am getting users from below function. This is vary complex. Can anybody tell me the simplest way to get users.

```
<?php

public function getUsers()
    {
        $bookmakers = collect();
        $auth = User::first();
        $clients = collect();
        if ($auth->is_super_admin()) {

            if (count($auth->clientsOfMine) > 0) {

                foreach ($auth->clientsOfMine as $key => $value) {
                    if ($value->is_sub_super_admin()) {
                        if (count($value->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                            foreach ($value->clientsOfMine as $value2) {
                                if ($value2->is_admin()) {
                                    if (count($value2->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($value2->clientsOfMine as $value3) {
                                            if ($value3->is_super_master()) {
                                                if (count($value3->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                                    foreach ($value3->clientsOfMine as $value4) {
                                                        if ($value4->is_master()) {
                                                            if (count($value4->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                                                foreach ($value4->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                                                    $clients->push($user);
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                        else if ($value4->is_user()) {
                                                            $clients->push($value4);
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else if ($value3->is_master()) {
                                                if (count($value3->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                                    foreach ($value3->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                                        $clients->push($user);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else if ($value3->is_user()) {
                                                $clients->push($value3);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else if ($value2->is_super_master()) {
                                    if (count($value2->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($value2->clientsOfMine as $value3) {
                                            if ($value3->is_master()) {
                                                if (count($value3->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                                    foreach ($value3->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                                        $clients->push($user);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else if ($value3->is_user()) {
                                                $clients->push($value3);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else if ($value2->is_master()) {
                                    if (count($value2->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($value2->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                            $clients->push($user);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else if ($value2->is_user()) {
                                    $clients->push($value2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($value->is_admin()) {
                        if (count($value->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                            foreach ($value->clientsOfMine as $value2) {
                                if ($value2->is_super_master()) {
                                    if (count($value2->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($value2->clientsOfMine as $value3) {
                                            if ($value3->is_master()) {
                                                if (count($value3->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                                    foreach ($value3->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                                        $clients->push($user);
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                            else if ($value3->is_user()) {
                                                $clients->push($value3);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if ($value2->is_master()) {
                                    if (count($value2->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($value2->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                            $clients->push($user);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if ($value2->is_user()) {
                                    $clients->push($value2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($value->is_super_master()) {
                        if (count($value->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                            foreach ($value->clientsOfMine as $value2) {
                                if ($value2->is_master()) {
                                    if (count($value2->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                                        foreach ($value2->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                            $clients->push($user);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else if ($value2->is_user()) {
                                    $clients->push($value);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($value->is_master()) {
                        if (count($value->clientsOfMine) > 0) {
                            foreach ($value->clientsOfMine as $user) {
                                $clients->push($user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($value->is_user()) {
                        $clients->push($value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return response()->json(['clients' =>$clients]);
    }
```

Comment: `each the "User" of child roles.` I don't understand what is a `child role`

Comment: @ChristopheHubert the role of each condition is child role. Like the child role of  "Super Admin" is "Sub Super Admin", "Admin", "Super Master" and "Master".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the purpose is of the `userid` column on the `users` table, also not sure if you've just made a typo and forgotten the underscore (`user_id`) and similarly with `client_id` on the `clients` table. Just use the `id` column on both tables for foreign key references.

If you're just wanting `users` with a lesser `role` than the current `user` then use a [query scope](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#query-scopes) to find `users` with a `role_id` greater than the current `user`.

```
public function scopeChildren($query)
{
  return $query->where('role_id', '>', $this->role_id);
}
```

If you want just the `users` with lesser `roles` that were `added/created` by the current `user` then add an extra column to your `users` table to store that relationship.

```
public function scopeChildren($query)
{
  return $query->where([
    ['role_id', '>', $this->role_id],
    ['created_by', '=', $this->id],
  ]);
}
```

Then call the `children` relationship on a `user`:

```
$user->children()->get();
```

Comment: Hello @Unflux  `$user->children()->get():` this will get only get only users of logged-in role. But I need users of all below roles. Let say if you are logged-in with **Sub Super Admin** than I need all the users of below roles which was added by **Sub Super Admin** not only current users of **Sub Super Admin**. Should I use recursion or add any column in `Users` table which is store the all parents Id or if you have any other logic ?

Comment: @NarendraChoudhary If I understand you correctly, you want all `users` with a `role` less than the `role` of the authenticated `user` but not limited to `users` they created? If that is the case them you want to use my first code snippet above which just searches for `users` with a lesser `role_id` then the `role_id` of the authenticated `user`.

Comment: First snippet only can get current client for just below hierarchy but if I want to get to get all the below hierarchy levels of particular logged in users then what will be your logic for this? like ex. - you are logged in with **Sub super admin** and I want all the clients of below hierarchy users.

Comment: The first snippet will get any `users` will a lesser `role_id` than that of the authenticated `user`. So everything less than the `sub super admin` role. If you want just those `users` who are logged in, you will need to add logic to check that in the scope.